# Finding work done by force with line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

**Problem**. Find the work done by the force $\renewcommand{\vec}{\overrightarrow}\vec{F}(x,y) = (x^2 - y^2) \ \vec{i} + 2xy \ \vec{j}$ in moving a particle counterclockwise around the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$, $(a,a)$, $(0,a)$, $a > 0$.

**Solution**. 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\vec{c}} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} &= \int_{\vec{c}} (x^2 - y^2) \ dx + 2xy \ dy \\
&= \int_0^a x^2 \ dx + \int_0^a 2ay \ dy - \int_0^a (x^2 - a^2) \ dx - \int_0^a 2 \cdot 0 \cdot y \ dy \\
&= \frac{x^3}{3} \bigg\vert_0^a + ay^2 \bigg\vert_0^a - \left(\frac{x^3}{3} - a^2 x \right) \bigg\vert_0^a - 0 \\
&= \frac{a^3}{3} + a^3 - \frac{a^3}{3} + a^3 \\
&= 2a^3.
\end{align*}

The problem and solution are given. Can someone explain to me how they set up these integrals? I'm really confused.

Comment: They evaluated the integral $\int_{\vec c}(x^2-y^2)\,dx + 2xy\,dy$ for each of the four line segments around the square and added them up.  For instance, in the first one -- from $(0,0)$ to $(a,0)$ -- we see $y=0$ so $dy = 0$.  So when you plug in, you get $\int_{x=0}^{x=a} x^2\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the [Green theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem), it is also handy for these problems:
$$
\oint_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_S\frac{\partial\;2xy}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial(x^2-y^2)}{\partial y}\;dS = \int_{x=0}^a\int_{y=0}^a4y\;dydx = 2a^3
$$

You have one integral to compute instead of four..